# Cannot boot into recovery (Samsung Galaxy S)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, recovery-mode, boot-loop, heimdall

My GT-I9000 device recently [got stuck in a bootloop](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48403/16575), and now I'm trying to put CyanogenMod on it, hoping that this would fix the situation.

I can use Heimdall to install the ClockworkMod Recovery on the phone, but as of today, I cannot boot into the recovery!

Yesterday everything worked normally, but once I tried to boot into it today, it got stuck in the bootloop instead of going to recovery!

I'm using the standard <kbd>Vol up</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> button combination.

What can I do to force the phone into recovery mode again?

**Edit:** CWM flashed (but unable to start) and honestly I can't remember how I initially bricked the device. I think it's safe to assume that I have a broken ROM on it.

I actually am trying to install a new ROM, so if I could flash it that would be great. But for that I need to get the recovery and ADB working.

Comment: I'm not sure if you already successfully flashed CWM. But assuming you did, and have not yet "fixed" the ROM itself, that could be the culprit. I have not worked with Samsung devices yet, but AFAIK you can bring them into two other modes for flashing: `fastboot` and `download` mode. Heimdall should be able to detect them at least in one of them. Maybe an "experienced Samsung-Flasher" can provide more help here.

Comment: i can easily get it into download mode and use Heimdall to flash the device with CWM, but the problem occurs when I try to boot into the CWM Recovery I've flashed onto the device. I was able to do that before, but not anymore, which is weird.

Comment: Have you already flashed another ROM, including a wipe? As I wrote on the previous question, it very much looks like something is messed up with your "old" ROM, so flashing a new one could solve that. Please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/48417/edit) your question and include the full current state of your device (CWM flashed? CM or another "fresh ROM" flashed?). Thanks!

Comment: Also I did the edit btw

Comment: Any error message from CWM? Sure you've picket a compatible version of it?

Comment: Nope, I don't even get to see any CWM output. And I'm sure because it's the same version that used to work before.

Answer (score 6):

I also had a boot loop today, after flashing Semaphore's ClockworkMod Recovery according to [these instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_galaxysmtd), then trying to boot to recovery mode. What helped me out was the hint at the bottom of that page: to use [Replicant's recovery.img](http://redmine.replicant.us/projects/replicant/wiki/ReplicantImages) instead:

```
heimdall flash --KERNEL recovery.img --no-reboot
```

**Update:** Note that the hint has now been removed with the comment:

> Using a non-Gingerbread-compatible recovery for initial install will result in lost IMEI.

Comment: Oh my God!! I thought the phone was lost until I tried your image. Finally CWM recovery that works! Thank you!

Comment: Robert, you deserve a medal...